# Error: no match for 'operator-' in 'temp - 5'

Tags: c++

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class STLstring
{
    private:
        string word;
    public:
    STLstring()
    {
        word = "";
    }
    void setWord(string w);
    string getWord();

};

class EncryptString:public STLstring
{
    private:
        void encrypt();
        void decrypt();
};


/*****************IMPLEMENTATION*******************/

void STLstring::setWord(string w)
{
    void encrypt();
    word = w;
    cout << word;
}

string STLstring::getWord()
{
    void decrypt();
    return word;
}

void EncryptString::encrypt()
{
    string temp = getWord();

    temp = (temp - 5) %26;



    setWord(temp);
}

void EncryptString::decrypt()
{
    string temp = getWord();



    setWord(temp);
}

int main()
{
    string word = "";
    EncryptString EncrptStr;

    cout << "Enter a word and I will encrypt it so that you cannot read it any longer." << endl;
    getline(cin, word);

    cout << "\nHere is the encrypted word..." << endl;
    EncrptStr.setWord(word);

    cout << "\nHere is the decrypted word..." << endl;
    cout << EncrptStr.getWord() << endl;
}
```

1 error within

```
temp = (temp - 5) %26;
```

Error says : no match for 'operator-' in 'temp - 5'
What i am trying to do is a ceasar cipher, I know i haven't finished the cipher yet but I think the error will still appear even though I finish it, am I supposed to make an overloaded operator in the class? If so how? I thought overloaded are only between two classes.

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is type `string` and you are specifying subtraction.  Either change the type to one which supports subtraction (like `int`) and change the logic accordingly, or implement `operator-` for a `string` and an `int`.

Comment: Do not implement `operator-` for string.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  I have clarified that part of my answer.  Care to explain your comment?

Comment: Such an operator would be _extremely_ surprising and its semantics unclear. Avoid the temptation to create one; it would be a perfect example of operator abuse. See urzeit's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `temp` is a string and strings don't have a subtraction. A statement like `"hello" - "world"` does not make sense, so defining one isn't a good idea usually.

In your case, you even try to subtract a number from a string ("hello" - 5), which does not make sense either.

If you want to calculate something, use number types (such as `int`, `float`, `double` or `long`).

Looking at your code I'm pretty sure you want to calculate something with the numerical value of the single chars in your string to 'encrypt' them. To do so, you have to operate on the chars of the string char by char. The type `char` is a numeric type, thus the calculation `'T'-'A'`is pretty ok, while `"T" - "A"` does not make sense.